# Why is $(H^{s}(\Gamma))^{*}=H^{-s}(\Gamma)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I start with short introduction. Let $\Omega$ be an open, connected and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $\Gamma$ denote the boundary of $\Omega$.

1) I cover $\Omega$ with a collection $\{U_1,…,U_M\}$ of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\Gamma\subset \bigcup_{r=1}^MU_r$ such that

$$\Gamma_r=U_r\cap\Gamma\neq\emptyset, \qquad r=1,…,M.$$

2) For each $U_r$, I introduce an orthogonal transformation $A_r$ of coorditate system $x=(x_1,…,x_d)$ into local coordinate system $y_r=(y_{r1},…,y_{rd}): y_r=A_r(x)$.

3) I assume that there exist $\alpha, \beta>0$ and functions $f_r$ (let's say Lipschitz functions for now) defined on sets $S_r$, where

$$S_r=\{y_r^{'}=(y_{r1},…,y_{rd-1})\,|\,|y_{ri}|<\alpha\}.$$

Now I demand the following construction:
$$\Gamma_{r}=U_r\cap \Gamma=\{(y_r^{'},f_{r}(y_{r}^{'}))\,|\,y_{r}^{'}\in S_{r}\},$$

$$U_r^{+}=U_{r}\cap \Omega=\{y_r\, |\,y_{r}^{'}\in S_{r},\, f_r(y_{r}^{'})<y_{rd}<f_{r}(y^{'}_{r})+\beta\},$$

$$U_r^{-}=U_{r}-cl(\Omega)=\{y_r\, |\,y_{r}^{'}\in S_{r},\, f_r(y_{r}^{'})-\beta<y_{rd}<f_{r}(y^{'}_{r})\}.$$

It follows from the construction, that $\Gamma$ can be described in the terms of hyperspaces (locally). The regularity of $\Gamma_r$ is assumed to be determined by choosing $k$ and $\lambda$ such that $f_r\in C^{k,\lambda}(cl(S_{r}))$.

**Theorem.** Indentyfying $H^{0}(\Gamma)$ with its dual, we have

$$(H^s(\Gamma))^*=H^{-s}(\Gamma).$$

What would be the proof?

My attempt is as follows: let $L$ be a continuous linear form on $H^{s}(\Gamma)$. Can it be written this way:
$$L(u)=\sum_{r=1}^{m} \langle g_j,u_r \rangle ,$$
$$g_j\in (H^{s}(S_{r}))^*=H^{-s}(S_r),\qquad (1)$$
where $u_{r}(y_{r}^{'})=u(y^{'}_{r}, f_{r}(y_{r}^{'}))$? Does it follow from Hahn-Banach theorem? Suppose I can do that. Now, I pick a function $\psi_{r}$ such that it is positive, has a compact support in $|y_{ri}|<\alpha$ for $i=1,…,d$ and $\psi_{r}=1$ in the neighbourhood of the suppoert of $u_{r}$. So

$$L(u)=\sum_{r=1}^{M}\langle\psi_rg_r, u_r\rangle$$
and I'm stuck. What should be done next?

Comment: What is your definition of $H^s(\Gamma)$ and $H^{-s}(\Gamma)$? By equality you mean that some natural map is an isomorphism?

Comment: Let $u_r(y_r^{'})=u(y_r^{'}, f_r(y_r^{'}))$. By functions $u\in L^2(\Gamma)$ I understood functions such that
$$(\sum_{r=1}^{M}\int_{S_r}|u_r(y^{'}_{r})|^{p}dy^{'}_{r}<\infty)^{1/p}.$$
Having this I can define Sobolov space $H^{s}(\Gamma)$. Also, I think I can define it via $f_r$ funtions.

$$H^{s}(\Gamma)=\{u\, |\, f_{r}\in H^{s}(S_r),\, r=1,...,M\}.$$

Comment: By equality $(H^{s}(\Gamma))^{*}=H^{-s}(\Gamma)$ I mean that I have to find a mapping which allows me to indentify every element of Sobolev space $H^{-s}(\Gamma)$ with an element of the dual to the $H^{s}(\Gamma)$ and the other way round - so as you said - an isomorphism.

Comment: I understand your definition of $L^2(\Gamma)$ (although I would define it wrt to the $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure on $\Gamma$), but I was asking about $H^s$ and $H^{-s}$. I see that you define these spaces by identifying pieces of $\Gamma$ with pieces of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, but my question remains: what is your definition of $H^s$ and $H^{-s}$? I believe including this information in your question would improve your chances for getting a valuable answer.

Comment: As for the isomorphism - all separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic (e.g. to $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$) by choosing an orthonormal basis, so this could make the question trivial. That's why I insisted on choosing the isomorphism.

Comment: I think I have already given the definition of $H^{s}(\Gamma)$. Once again $$H^{s}(\Gamma)=\{u\,|\,f_r\in H^{s}(S_r),\,r=1,...,M\}.$$ As you noticed, every piece of $\Gamma$ is locally seen as subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$  ($H^{s}(S_r)=W^{s,2}(S_r)$). I want to keep it this way because I want to make a use of (1). The same way I define $H^{-s}$. As far as the norms are concerned $$<u,v>_{H^{s}(\Gamma)}=\sum_{r=1}^{M}\int_{S_r}|u_r(y^{'}_{r})v_r(y^{'}_{r})|dy_{r}^{'}+\sum_{|\alpha|\le s}\sum_{r=1}^{M}\int_{S_r}|D^{\alpha}u_r(y^{'}_{r})D^{\alpha}v_r(y^{'}_{r})|dy_{r}^{'}$$

Comment: Is $s$ a natural number? This norm is not suitable for arbitrary $s>0$. And what about $s<0$?

Comment: You are right - the above scalar product is suitable for $s$ being natural, while I'm interested in $s\in (0,1)$ and in particular $s=1/2$.  Let $$\|u\|_{H^{s}(\Gamma)}=(\sum_{r=1}^{M}\int_{S_r}|u_r(y^{'}_{r})|^2dy^{'}_{r}+\sum_{r=1}^{M}\int_{S_r}\int_{S_r}\frac{|u_{r}(y^{'}_{r}-u(x_{r}^{'}))|}{|y_{r}^{'}-x_{r}^{'}|^{d+2s}}dy^{'}_{r}dx_{r}^{'})^{1/2}.$$